# Array elements in annotations used as single values

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

What happens when we declare an array in an Annotation and use it like this:

```
@interface MyAnno {
    String[] names();
}

@MyAnno(names="some value")
class { ... }
```

Although the element `names` is declared as an Array of String, we can use it as  a String, providing a single value without curly braces. I guess that's a good thing and that's how `SuppressWarnings` work, I just want to know what happens internally when we do that? How the compiler handles this? Does it replace `names` with a String named `names`, or applies `{}` where the annotation is used? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Language specification:

*Identifier* = *ElementValue*

*If the element type is an array type, then it is not required to use curly braces to specify the element value of the element-value pair. If the element value is not an ElementValueArrayInitializer, then an array value whose sole element is the element value is associated with the element.*

It's syntactic sugar - you get an array with a single element.

Comment: "If the element value is not an ElementValueArrayInitializer, then an array value whose sole element is the element value is associated with the element", so that's what happens.